# "Network Error" when I try to create a .NET Core 3.1 AWS Lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I tried to create an AWS Lambda with a .NET Core 3.1 (C#/PowerShell) runtime. I am using the "Author from scratch" option with `Test` as the function name. I didn't change any of the permissions, the default execution permissions, or the Advanced settings.

When I try to create the lambda, I get the rather generic error message "Network Error" (with no further details).

I get the exact same problem when I try to use a .NET Core 2.1 runtime environment.

When I try Node.js 14.x, I can create the lambda just fine.

Am I missing some step to set this up? Or is there some kind of problem in AWS itself?

Comment: Can you provide some more specifics?  What does your function look like?  "When I try to create the lambda" - how are you trying to create it?  Are you using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-package-cli.html

Comment: @PhilipPittle I'm doing it via the UI, not the CLI. There is no Lambda yet because I can't even get to the point where I'd enter the code.

Comment: Is your browser/3rd party plugins blocking any scripts? Brave, FireFox.  uMatrix, uBlock

Comment: @PhilipPittle Yeah, that's a good point... would blocking tracking content and third-party cookies make any difference here? Or should I look for other things that might be being blocked?

Comment: I generally browse with uMatrix which blocks by domain.  I've certainly noticed parts of the AWS Console site becoming unusable if my filters are too aggressive.  Do a run with your filters disabled.